# Cordova FileTransfer plugin not working on Android 5+

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-transfer, phonegap

I'm building an app with PhoneGap Build, only targeting Android. One of the features is to download a file from a web server to the device.

This code works perfectly on Android 4.x, but doesn't work on Android 5.x and above:

```js
var URL = 'https://example.com/path/to/file.pdf?auth_token=123xxxx';
var Folder_Name = 'Download';
var File_Name = URL.split('/');
File_Name = File_Name[File_Name.length - 1].split('?');
File_Name = File_Name[0];

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
 var download_link = encodeURI(URL);

 var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
 directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, {
  create: true,
  exclusive: false
 }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
 var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
 var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fullpath of local directory

 fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
 console.log("Path to local file: " + fp);
 // download function call
 filetransfer(download_link, fp);
}

function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
 console.log('directory created successfully');
 // Directory created successfuly
}

function onDirectoryFail(error) {
 //Error while creating directory
 console.log("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

function fileSystemFail(evt) {
 //Unable to access file system
 console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
 var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
 // File download function with URL and local path
 fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
  function(entry) {
   alert('The file was successfully downloaded, you can access it in /' + Folder_Name + '/' + File_Name + '.');
   console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
  },
  function(error) {
   //Download abort errors or download failed errors
   console.log("download error source " + error.source);
   console.log("download error target " + error.target);
   console.log("download error code" + error.code);
  }
 );
}
```

Don't get anything in the console, no error and none of the log lines, meaning that none of the callbacks gets triggered.

Did anybody else have this mysterious issue?

Thanks

Comment: do you have the latest version of file transfer plugin? I think they fixed the permission issues

Comment: I've added <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" /> in config.xml, meaning it takes the latest version, at the moment 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

try to install these versions.

```
phonegap plugin remove cordova-plugin-file
phonegap plugin remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer

phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1
```

I am use these versions and i havent problems in Anrdoid 5, 6, 7. Try it.